# Precincts where Trump got <1% of the vote in 2016?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, voting, presidential-election, hillary-clinton

I read an article about Trump's historically bad performance in the capitol city of the US. I saw that there were at least two precincts where he did *EXTREMELY* badly. There were two precincts that I could find where this happened: Precinct 100 (0.8%), and Precinct 125 (0.88%). Each of these precincts had over 1,000 votes cast in this election. This is not about these precincts, but if there are any other precincts where Trump did this badly.

Are there any other precincts with over 250 votes where Donald Trump received less than one percent of the vote?

https://wamu.org/story/16/11/14/trump_may_be_moving_to_town_but_dc_voted_against_him_like_nowhere_else/

Answer (score 12):

According to MIT Election Data and Science Lab's [U.S. President Precinct-Level Returns 2016 dataset](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/LYWX3D), there were around 580 such precincts (the precise number is difficult to count as some counties seem to report write-ins, etc as separate precincts). For example:

- Davidson County's 601 precinct in Tennessee gave 1207 votes out of 1277 to Evan McMullin, and none to either Trump or Clinton.
- Larimer County's 2145235206  precinct in Colorado gave 965 votes out of 1111 to Clinton, and most of the rest to Gary Johnson or Jill Stein.

Here is a summary of the precincts where Trump's vote share was less than 1%, though as I said there may be some mistakes due to how certain types of votes are counted.

```
                                                                       Donald Trump  Hillary Clinton  Total   Trump %
state        county_name          precinct                                                                            
Tennessee    Davidson County      601                                              0                0   1277  0.000000
             Rutherford County    50                                               0                0    481  0.000000
Ohio         Cuyahoga County      CLEVELAND-02-R                                   0              419    425  0.000000
Alabama      Mobile County        THOMAS SULLIVAN COMM CENTER #1                   0              280    532  0.000000
Louisiana    Pointe Coupee Parish 00 13A                                           0              390    392  0.000000
             St. James Parish     00 07                                            0              291    292  0.000000
Maryland     Baltimore city       School No. 35                                    0              277    281  0.000000
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  2830                                             0              349    350  0.000000
Colorado     Larimer County       2145235206                                       0              965   1111  0.000000
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  3430                                             0              266    268  0.000000
                                  5890                                             0              308    312  0.000000
                                  1230                                             0              277    285  0.000000
                                  2170                                             0              404    406  0.000000
                                  6230                                             0              278    280  0.000000
                                  7090                                             0              282    282  0.000000
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 20 Precinct 12                              0              432    438  0.000000
                                  Ward 09 Precinct 05                              0              417    423  0.000000
                                  Ward 24 Precinct 35                              0              433    438  0.000000
New Jersey   Camden County        Pennsauken Twp                                   0                0    265  0.000000
Alabama      Jefferson County     2370 - NEW BETHEL BAPTIS                         1              487    946  0.105708
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 09 Precinct 26                              1              663    670  0.149254
Alabama      Montgomery County    211 RUFUS LEWIS LIBRARY #2                       1              342    620  0.161290
             Mobile County        THOMAS SULLIVAN COMM CENTER #2                   1              288    557  0.179533
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  11150                                            1              510    516  0.193798
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 08 Precinct 36                              1              496    514  0.194553
Louisiana    Caddo Parish         00 057                                           1              496    500  0.200000
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 21 Precinct 09                              1              495    499  0.200401
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  7460                                             1              484    488  0.204918
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 17 Precinct 18                              1              472    482  0.207469
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  12120                                            1              461    467  0.214133
...                                                                              ...              ...    ...       ...
Alabama      Jefferson County     2380 - FIVE POINTS WEST                         12              642   1240  0.967742
Michigan     Wayne County         DETROIT CITY; 373                                4              397    412  0.970874
Ohio         Cuyahoga County      CLEVELAND-09-Q                                   3              300    308  0.974026
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 17 Precinct 35                              4              398    409  0.977995
Mississippi  Hinds County         Precinct 11                                      3              302    306  0.980392
New Jersey   Hudson County        Jersey City WF D24                               5              499    510  0.980392
Missouri     St. Louis city       W 04 P 06                                        3              298    306  0.980392
Mississippi  Sunflower County     Indianola #2 East                               15             1496   1529  0.981033
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  12390                                            4              395    407  0.982801
                                  11120                                            5              480    508  0.984252
New York     Kings County         061/58                                           2              211    254  0.787402
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 21 Precinct 02                              4              393    406  0.985222
Wisconsin    Milwaukee County     CITY OF MILWAUKEE Ward 107                       7              691    710  0.985915
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 37 Precinct 35                              5              496    507  0.986193
Ohio         Cuyahoga County      CLEVELAND-01-F                                   6              595    608  0.986842
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 24 Precinct 29                              3              298    304  0.986842
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  6990                                             3              298    304  0.986842
                                  8720                                             3              299    304  0.986842
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 24 Precinct 13                              3              293    304  0.986842
Michigan     Genesee County       FLINT CITY; Ward 1; Precinct 1                   9              894    911  0.987925
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 09 Precinct 43                              5              490    506  0.988142
Missouri     St. Louis city       W 01 P 04                                        5              494    506  0.988142
Illinois     St. Clair County     PRECINCT 02                                      5              496    505  0.990099
Pennsylvania Philadelphia County  2500                                             4              398    404  0.990099
                                  2210                                             4              394    403  0.992556
Georgia      Chatham County       8-10 Carver Heights Community Center             2              247    251  0.796813
California   Alameda County       336100                                           3              302    352  0.852273
Illinois     Cook County          Ward 08 Precinct 52                              6              591    603  0.995025
Michigan     Wayne County         DETROIT CITY; 361                                6              585    602  0.996678
Alabama      Jefferson County     2170 - HEMPHILL SCHOOL R                        21             1073   2101  0.999524

[578 rows x 4 columns]
```