# What percentage of voters lived in a precinct where Republican house candidate got less than 5% of the vote in 2016 and 2018?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, statistics

I am interested in "Republican free zones". They are seldom *completely* Republican free, but they are called such because you could have 10 neighbors and not know a single Republican voter. These are places with few or no Republican votes. I will define a Republican free zone a little bit more loosely, as a precinct with less than 5 percent of the two party vote. On the county level, there is only one such location, which is (of course) the District of Columbia in 2018's House election, as well as the 2016 presidential election.

[image: Visualization]
<sub>Source: [Emily Badger - NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/21/upshot/america-political-divide-urban-rural.html)</sub>

This is a visualization of the 2016 *presidential* election. I want to know about the House elections and whether or not more voters live in such a location. I am not asking for a complete list, but I am asking for how prevalent such a precinct was in 2016 and 2018. In the presidential election, it was 3.6%. My data suggests that it was less than that in 2016 and at least that for 2018.

To be clear I want the % of votes cast in such a precinct where data is easily publicly available and candidates of both major parties ran in 2016 and 2018. My guess is that it would be less than the share of voters in the presidential election because there are unopposed congressional elections but not unopposed presidential elections.

See also: [Precincts where Trump got <1% of the vote in 2016?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52980/precincts-where-trump-got-1-of-the-vote-in-2016)

Answer (score 5):

Using the MEDSL precinct datasets for the [2016](https://github.com/MEDSL/official-precinct-returns/tree/master/2016-precinct-house) & [2018](https://github.com/MEDSL/2018-elections-official/) House elections, we can get some idea of these figures. Note that neither dataset is 100% accurate or complete due to inconsistent reporting - especially the 2018 dataset, which doesn't include New York - see the MEDSL GitHub for full details.

Nevertheless, these datasets appear to be the best available, and we can draw some rudimentary conclusions from these data.

In 2016, 278,645 precincts have data available, with a total of 90,699,658 voters. 6,425, or about 2.3%, had a Democratic two-party vote share of >95%, with a total of 2,586,188 voters, or about 2.85%.

[image]

In 2018, 144,304 precincts have data available, with a total of 72,283,342 voters. 5,346 precincts, or about 3.7%, had a Democratic two-party vote share of >95%, with a total of 1,698,184 voters, or about 2.35%.

[image]